# jsPlumb: dragging new connection should remove existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Using jsPlumb, I managed to have the following setup:

- There are multiple nodes acting like nodes in a special type of flowchart.
- Each node has one single target where connections can be dropped onto.
- Every node has zero, one or more exits. Each exit acts as jsPlumb source, and is allowed to have one connection at most.

Little example first: http://fiddle.darkspot.ch/ivr/flowchart/ivrplumb.html
(after an hour of trying, I unfortunately didn't get it to run on jsFiddle - so I host it myself)

What I want to achieve is:
If the user drags a new connection from an exit to another node, it should be established as intended. But all the other connections being on this exit should be removed.

I tried different approaches:

- Having a [`click` listener](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/events#evt-connection) (links to jsPlumb documentation) on each exit bubble. Doesn't work -> the event never gets fired no matter what I tried.
- Having an instance [`connection` listener](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/events#endpointEvents) . I thought I could get the existing connections from the endpoint in the `info` object I'm receiving. Open the console while looking at the example, and you see it's always `1`, no matter how many connections there are.
- Limiting `maxConnections` for the `makeSource(...)` call to `1`. This would actually work, but the user cannot drag another connection to replace the first.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Move your mouse to one of the orange squares, click and drag a connection another node. (connection should establish)
2. Open your browser's javascript console
3. Move your mouse to the same square and click/drag another connection to the same or another target node. (second connection should establish. watch the console printing `Number of connections:1`. This should be `2` here)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before a new connection is established check whether the source already has outgoing connections, If so remove it. Assuming that exit elements have `exit` class:

```
jsPlumb.bind('beforeDrop', function(ci){ // Before new connection is created
    var src=ci.sourceId;
    var con=jsPlumb.getConnections({source:src}); // Get all source el. connection(s) except the new connection which is being established 
    if(con.length!=0 && $('#'+src).hasClass('exit')){
        for(var i=0;i<con.length;i++){
            jsPlumb.detach(con[i]);
        }
    }
    return true; // true for establishing new connection
});
```

Comment: +1 & Accept: That's cool, it works - thanks! In the same place, I can now check whether the user is trying to drag the connection to the node the exit belongs to - which I want to avoid. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a global array variable and push every new connections to the array

```
    var cons = [];
    instance.bind("connection", function (info) {
        var src = info.sourceId;
        var trgt = info.targetId;
        if (!cons.includes(src+trgt)) {//if not exists
           cons.push(src+trgt);
           cons.push(trgt+src);//(optional) use to prevent adding connection from target to source 
        }
    });
```

then in the beforeDrop check if the new connection that you are going to create already exists from the array.

```
    instance.bind('beforeDrop', function(info){
        var createCon = true;
        var src = info.sourceId;
        var trgt = info.targetId;
        var newCon = src + trgt;
        if(cons.includes(newCon)){//if new connection exists do not allow to create new connection
            createCon = false;
        }
        return createCon;
    });
```

And remove the element in the array when removing connections.

```
    instance.bind("click", function (info) {
        var el = cons.indexOf(info.sourceId + info.targetId);
        var el2 = cons.indexOf(info.targetId + info.sourceId);
        cons.splice(el, 1);
        cons.splice(el2, 1);
        instance.deleteConnection(info);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm use JSPLUMB on angular project and i did this solution:

Delete the connection if exist, before drop a new connection:

```
    this.jsPlumbInstance.bind('beforeDrop', params => {
  // DELETA CONEXAO CASO JA EXISTE PARA CRIAR OUTRA
  // REMOVE CURRENT CONNECTION IF EXIST TO CREATE NEW
  this.jsPlumbInstance.getConnections().map(connection => {
    if (connection.targetId === params.targetId && connection.sourceId === params.sourceId) {
      this.jsPlumbInstance.deleteConnection(connection);
    }
  });
});
```

JSPLUMB haven't a 'afterDrop' bind, so keep this solution.